# How two diffrent projects running on java and .net can interact with each other using WCF?

Tags: wcf, java-client

I have a wcf services projects and a second project for consuming these services is in java.
My question is how can i create proxy classes for java to consume my wcf services ?
Is there any other way to consume wcf services through Java clients ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WCF is like a wrapper for all kind of communication you might want to do.

So if you want, you can make your wcf services use SOAP as a communication method, which the java side should be able to implement.

[More info about wcf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731082.aspx)